# How to collapse all the panels in the richfaces accordion by default

Tags: java, jsf-2, richfaces

I wonder how do I set the richfaces accordion collapse by default

This is my code, I just want all panel collapse on load the page

```
<rich:accordion 
    switchType="ajax" style="width : 680px">
        <c:forEach items="#{marcarConsulta.consultasDisponiveis}"
            var="consultaDisponivel" varStatus="contador">
            <rich:accordionItem value="#{consultaDisponivel}">
                <f:facet name="header">                 
                    <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="10"
                        columnClasses="titulo_accordion_item">
                        <h:outputText value="#{consultaDisponivel.nomePessoa}" />
                        <h:outputText value="#{consultaDisponivel.nomeFantasia}" />
                    </h:panelGrid>
                </f:facet>
                <h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="accordion-date">
                    <h2>Escolha uma data:</h2>
                    <rich:calendar popup="false"
                        value="#{marcarConsulta.dataSelecionada}" mode="ajax"
                        firstWeekDay="0" boundaryDatesMode="scroll"
                        dataModel="#{calendarModel}" datePattern="dd/MM/yyyy">
                        <f:ajax listener="#{marcarConsulta.recuperarHorario}"
                            render="horario#{contador.index}" />
                    </rich:calendar>
                </h:panelGroup>             
            </rich:accordionItem>
        </c:forEach>
</rich:accordion>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you define a css class as below :

```
<style> .myclass { display:none}  </style>
```

then on the accordion items add this to the contentClass attribute like this :

```
<rich:accordionItem contentClass="myclass" switchType="ajax"  >
```

then you should see that you now have all panels collapsed.
Clicking on them will now expand as usual.

Comment: thanks @Marcus Blackhall, now I have another problem, when I render the accordion with f:ajax, click on any of the items does not work until I reload the page, any idea, thanks again

Comment: Can you post more detail. Where are you using the f:ajax control.

Comment: Hi @Marcus Blackhall, I posted the question in this topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13252301/why-the-accordion-richfaces-does-not-work-after-being-rendered-using-the-tag-f, thanks for the help

Comment: Two things. Can you first try it without ajax ? using server mode instead. ? Let me know if it now works . And then can you ensure that the rendered attribute is true on initial construction of your bean.

Comment: It worked yes, thanks for the help, sorry for the delay in responding.